# Parameter value [20.0] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here is a function in my Java application :

```
public List<History> test(Double amount) {
    String q = "SELECT h FROM History  h WHERE (h.amount/POW(10,h.amountPrecision)) = :amount";
    Query query = em.createQuery(q);

    query.setParameter("amount", amount);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

For example, in my database I have `amount = 2000` and `amountPrecision = 2`. Since I can the operation in my query can be decimal, my parameter is a `Double` and I enter 20.00 in my application.

```
Parameter value [20.0] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]
```

In my Data Object `amount` is a `Long` and `amountPrecision` is an `Integer`. Any idea ? Thanks ;)

Comment: try: `query.setParameter("amount", (long)amount);` because amount is a Double.

Answer (score 1):

In your method test(Double amount) amount has data type Double but in WHERE clause in left side is long data type and in right side must me long too.

May be you must change your method test signature to:

```
public List<History> test(Long amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to:

```
SELECT h FROM History  h WHERE (cast(h.amount as double)/POW(10,h.amountPrecision)) = :amount
```

Comment: I'm having Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:55)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

`query.setParameter("amount",amount.longValue());`

You are passing a `double` value in the place where you should put a `Long` value.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by changing query in :

```
"SELECT h FROM History  h WHERE (CONVERT(h.amount, DECIMAL)/POW(10,h.amountPrecision)) = :amount"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
query.setParameter("amount", new Double(amount));
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding how this helps and works.